# View cookies using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

When I use inspect element on Chrome I can navigate to Application > Storage > Cookies > url and view the cookies, but document.cookie returns nothing. Why is this?

Comment: Are they `httpOnly` cookies? Those are protected if so

Comment: It could be, so you're saying even though I can see it with my eyes I can't see it using JavaScript? There isn't any way around that?

Comment: *"it could be"* ... can tell in browser dev tools what type it is. If it is set at server as httpOnly, no...you can't access it with script for security reasons